# Calendar on Angular 2 using PrimeNG date in milliseconds

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, primeng

I have time in milliseconds in calendar component of PrimeNG

**HTML**

```html
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="task.startDate"
    [minDate]="minDateValue"
    [maxDate]="maxDateValue"
    readonlyInput="readonlyInput"
    [showIcon]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

**TypeScript**

```
"startDate":1490039621704,
```

But instead I am getting the following error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function
TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function
```

Is there a way to tell the component to read the date in specific format, like in my case it is milliseconds

### Update

According to documentation [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar), date format in milliseconds should be *@ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)*
 so I added attribute `dateFormat="@"` to the component, but doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the error, it is expecting a [Date Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Try:

```
date = new Date(task.startDate);
```

#### Possibility base on OP update.

The error may happen before server response with `task.startDate` value. If that is the case, initializing `task.startDate` with 0 at the component level may fix the issue.

```
export class AppComponent {

    task = { startDate: 0 };

    ...

}
```

Comment: Start date is actually response from server I'm not doing anything in ts

Comment: i'll update the oode later to show my actual code, but i'm not doing anything on ts (and hopefully won't have to), since it is an array of objects im getting from server and i am using *ngFor loop on the html table to display an editable timepicker grid, actually i tried also using ng2-bootstrap datepicker , but seems like their datepicker  only works inline, doesn't have popup option